# Form is not working when used with if(isset($_POST("submit")))

Tags: php

My form is not working when used with 
`if(isset($_POST["submit"]))`
Please help

```
<form name="form"  onsubmit="return chkEntry()"  action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
<fieldset>          
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="ema" />            
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="text"  style="visibility:hidden" name="tut" value="<?php echo $tu?> "/>
    <input type="text"  style="visibility:hidden" name="file" value="<?php echo $fi?> "/>
    <input type="text"  style="visibility:hidden" name="file" value="<?php echo $fi?> "/>
    <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Submit" align="right"/></p> </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: `$_POST` is not a function, it’s an array. Use `$_POST[…]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`$_POST` is an **array**, not a function name. So it should be `$_POST[KEY]`. And as key you use input's `name`, not `value` as you tried. Not to mention you should type it correctly - you probably wanted `submit` but ended in `sumit`. But it should be `enter` anyway ;). So if you want to check if submit button was hit, then you should do

```
if( isset( $_POST['enter'] ) ) {
   // form submitted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is named `submit` where as you looking for `sunmit` to be POSTED.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there's nothing associated to `$_POST("sunmit")` which is a wrong syntax by the way. If you had an element called `sunmit`, you would access it using `$_POST['sunmit']`.

Try `print_r($_POST)` to see all variables that are being passed from the form to the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

**instead of using** `if(isset($_POST("sunmit")))` **use** `if(isset($_POST("enter")))`   as your name of submit button is **enter**

Answer (score 0):

you dont have a sunmit button , so this one wont work '$_POST("sunmit")'.

. Please use the follwoing to get form to be submitted:

if( isset( $_POST['enter'] ) ) {

}